People in a mansion play games to win money
I watched it when I was little, around 2007 or so. I know it was a group of people that were sent to a mansion and play games to win money.

One girl was sent home but the guy that was on the road with her stopped and buried her alive.
Another girl that was suppose to be sent home too but they killed her and put her inside a cow and the whole group had to eat from the cow without knowing the female was in it.
At the end they all find out but are forced to play for their lives and one girl survives at the end but she's inside a box that moves you from spot to spot in the air and all the people inside the box are forced to play.


Is there anything more you can tell us about the movie? How old is the movie? We don't know when you were little. :)

Honestly i don't know how old it is but i watched it around 2007 or so.

@noeliarico Feel free to [edit] this information into the question. You might also want to chose a more descriptive title.

You saw this when you were little??

@his op elaborated on that saying around 2007.

I think 'his' is just shocked that the OP watched a movie like this when they were little... And so am I, sort of. ;)

Cruel World from 2005 with Edward Furlong, Aimee Garcia and Jaime Pressly. It's about a contestant from a Bachelor-type reality show who's gone insane that takes over the house that it was filmed in. He then pretends it's the setting of a new reality show and invites a bunch of young people there to compete in various challenges for a cash prize, except he gradually disposes of them with his brother. One of the women is driven out of there and buried alive. There's also an eating challenge where the contestants have to eat a cow carcass, and don't realize that there's a woman in it. In the end, the final girl boards a cable car with a group of people when the mad 'host', who escaped, appears on her phone. Here's the trailer:




you are really a movie genius huh? and youtube is your weapon :)
